# Render Template Exactly with Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm a complete newb to Django working on a sample app. It appears that I am missing something with how templates work in Django.

I have a template file as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Zabba Dabba Doo</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Zabba Dabba Doo</h1>

<form action="/comparison/search/" method="get">
Search: <input type="text" name="search_terms" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The views.py method is here:

```
def home(request):
   t = loader.get_template('comparison/index.html')
   return HttpResponse(t)
```

I am expecting the views method to render the html from my template, but when I test it, this is the resulting output:

```
<Text Node: '<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<h'>
```

Can anyone explain to me how to make it so my template is displayed exactly? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to [render it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context).

Comment: Hi Abrams, could you pls have a look into my question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085439/render-to-response-or-redirect-changes-the-template-elements-in-django-1-8