# render_to_response or redirect changes the template elements in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to check if email id entered by user is existing in the database table, if existing - I would like to route to 'prof.html' template otherwise just show  a message in the login.html template.

Both the conditions are working fine.

However, the problem is when I use redirect() or render_to_response() - 
the destination template elements like div, input etc., are being changed automatically (prof.html in this case) ?

Can we also send the context information to destination template ?
(response data or any object from the database and redirect to prof.html template via view in this case)

Below is my code :

**Views.py**

```
def verifyme(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        emailid4loginV = request.POST['emailid4login_Aj']
    else:
        emailid4loginV = '' 
        response_data = ''
        return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="text/plain")
    response_data = ''
    if Employee.objects.filter(email = emailid4loginV).exists():
        response_data='Thanks for waiting - login successful'
        #return render_to_response('app/prof.html', { 'response_data':response_data}, 
        #                           context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )
        return redirect('/myprofile')
    else:
        response_data='Ouch! you are not a registered user!'
    return HttpResponse(response_data, content_type="text/plain")
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^myprofile$', 'app.views.profile', name='profile'),
```

Just for your info, 'profile' view does return some objects from the table and renders in the template app/prof.html.

I observed that the destination template is being rendered in same login.html template (How ? : In the browser url, I dont see myprofile - but the one for login)  But when I request the myprofile manually by entering in the website url (localhost:xxxxx/myprofile), it works perfectly :(

URL before submitting request in login.html :

[image]

URL after submitting request in login.html - myprofile is rendered in the same page :

[image]

When I manually type in the url, template just works perfectly.. 
[image]

Could you please let me know what could be the problem ?

**EDIT:**
Solved this issue with a little trick, posted in the below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091938/why-is-httpresponseredirectreverse-doesnt-redirect-to-new-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Actually there are many ways to pass data to next view ... generally in such cases like you have better way - using sessions (cookie|localstorage|sessionstorage), it is like clipboard ... save session data in one view and get it later in another one. For example:

First view:

```
self.request.session['response_data'] = 'some text'
self.request.session.set_expiry(0)  # user’s session cookie will expire when the user’s Web browser is closed.
```

Other views:

```
response_data = self.request.session.get('response_data', '')
```

But if you planning just use this data in template Django has some kind more high-level interface for it and in your case semantically right to use it -  **The messages framework** https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/

2) If you want redirect to another view better use url namespaces and `reverse` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(app.views.profile))  # here I've passed callable object because you have not show your app url namespace, but generally use namespaces
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

Comment: Thank you mate!.. Its good learning for me. I will try and let you know.

Comment: It throws error while running return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(app.views.profile)), "NameError: app is not defined".. Application name is app.. and I have the url pattern defined in the project urls.py (main one).. I dont have any other urls.py file. any help ?

Comment: ah I thought app is app name :D not project ... misunderstand 'cause project can contain many apps ... try simply **profile**

Comment: It works when I use  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile')).. but the problem still exists.. my destination template (prof.html) elements are getting changed.. and I dont see the '/myprofile' in the browser url :(

Comment: Are you sure Employee.objects.filter(email = emailid4loginV).exists() **is True**?

Comment: show full urls.py if you sure return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('profile')) has been called

Comment: yes.. I'm sure objects.filter(email = emailid4loginV).exists()  is true.. as I did test earlier by returing HttpResonse with response_data to my login template

Comment: url(r'^myprofile$', 'app.views.profile', name='profile'), is the url..  if you want to see the profile view code, I can update in the question ?